# Creating dom elements in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

what is the easiest way of dynamically creating a DOM elements in component? I have a model of a tree (items with parentId param) loaded from API and I need to print them out into nested lists like

```
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two with subitems:
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *ngFor to create dom elements dynamically in angular2

```
<ul>
 <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
<li *ngFor="let item of list">
  {{item.title}} // just assuming
  <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
  </ul>
</li>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"> </ng-container>
</ul>
```

You need to change code according to your model

Please check [gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use ngFor but consider my example - items with parentId parameter. How would you create multi-level list this way if you dont know how many child lists it would have?

Comment: @Gatekeeper use recursion: create a TreeNode component that displays a node name, and then uses ngFor to display all its children using the TreeNode component.

Comment: Oh, thats brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gatekeeper, I am glad it helped you. Please update and accept it as answer, it might help others

Answer (score 1):

[Structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) is for you.

> This guide looks at how Angular manipulates the DOM with structural directives and how you can write your own structural directives to do the same thing.